# Android Studio - i-Programmer Tutorial - MainActivity implements View.onClickListener - Cannot resolve symbol error

Tags: onclicklistener, android-studio-2.0

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/android/10051-android-adventures-events.html?start=1

If you scroll down the header: Implement the interface in the activity

The picture shows an implement error, though I'm getting the 'Cannot resolve symbol Error'

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
// import android.view.View.OnClickListener

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.onClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Handle event
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start with a capital letter on OnClickListener, change:

```
... implements View.onClickListener {
```

to

```
... implements View.OnClickListener {
```

Additionally, since you have imported:

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

you can ommit `View` in `View.OnClickListener`, that is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {
```

Also, as a suggestion for future questions, please insert your code as text in the question, not as an image as it makes it possible for us to copy-paste rather than rewrite everything.